# Is there a limit on number of placemarks returned by Google Maps Geocoding API v2?

Tags: maps, geocoding

So, the question is: is there a limit on number of placemarks returned by Google Maps Geocoding API v2? I searched through the web but this limit (if it exists) is nowhere explicitly stated. However I've never seen Geocoding API return more than 10 placemarks regardless of how common the input is (there is Lenin str. in every Russian town but Maps.app on my iPhone returns just 9 placemarks). Any thoughts on that?

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to by-pass the limit by exporting the map as a kml file using the View in Google Earth link at the top of the map. You will need to host this kml file in a publicly accessible server and you load it into maps by searching the Google map for the URL of the KML file.
The problem for a collaboration map is that the process will need to be repeated every time that the My Map map is updated.